# TypeError __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'uploads_to'

Tags: python, django, constructor

I created models for my project but am getting the following error. Help.
[image]

Comment: Please add code and error messages as text, not as a screenshot.

Comment: Run following command after saving models.py file.
python manage.py makemigrations 
and then
python manage.py migrate

Answer (score 2):

According to [the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ImageField) the argument is called `upload_to`, not `uploads_to`.

Comment: Even that is not working